# Replacing sh with zsh

Tags: shell, ubuntu, zsh

I have replaced sh with zsh with the following commands:

```
$ sudo mv /bin/sh /bin/sh1
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/zsh /bin/sh
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Jul  6 20:48 /bin/sh -> /usr/bin/zsh
$ which sh
/bin/sh
$ sh
$ exit
$ zsh
mpc% exit
```

As you can see, the `sh` command doesn't open a `zsh` shell although it has been linked. The question is why? How can I fix that?

Comment: Expecting all those existing bash scripts to suddenly work with zsh is unrealistic.  http://slopjong.de/2012/07/02/compatibility-between-zsh-and-bash/

Comment: That is not an issue here, steve.  This is Ubuntu.  `/bin/sh` has not been expected to be the Bourne Again shell for 12 years, [since version 6.10](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not change your user's default shell using `chsh` instead.

```
$ chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh
```

#### References

- [Installing ZSH](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Installing-ZSH)

Answer (score 6):

It's supposed to do that. If you start it as `sh`, it assumes you want something that's mostly compatible with other shells called `sh`, and runs in a compatibility mode.

See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Invocation.html#Compatibility:

> Zsh tries to emulate *sh* or *ksh* when it is invoked as `sh` or `ksh` respectively; [...]
>
> In *sh* and *ksh* compatibility modes the following parameters are not special and not initialized by the shell: ... `prompt`, `PROMPT`, ...
>
> The usual zsh startup/shutdown scripts are not executed.

I'm not sure if it's possible to have not work in compatibility mode when called as `sh`, but that might break a number of scripts on your system that assume `/bin/sh` is just `sh`, not Zsh.

Probably best to run it as `zsh` instead.

Comment: Correct, if called `sh`, it is mostly shell compatible, but slower. So you may suffer from longer boot times.