# Why I can't add fish to /etc/shells?

Tags: shell, command-line, osx, fish

I'm trying to use fish shell as my default shell on OSX. I have installed fish shell using brew and when I wanted to add it to `/etc/shells` I got this error:

```
tee: /etc/shells: No such file or directory
```

Here's the command line I used:

```
echo "usr/local/bin/fish" | sudo tee -a /etc/shells
```

Source: https://hackercodex.com/guide/install-fish-shell-mac-ubuntu/

Is there something wrong with my `$PATH`?

Comment: slm's answer works. Even if you successfully add it to `/etc/shells` which you could just do with a text editor, you'd still have to run the `chsh` command to make it your default shell.

Comment: Can it be you mistyped the path? Yours: "usr/local/blabla" --> My guess: "/usr/local/blabla". There's the root path missing.

Answer (score 12):

You're doing it wrong. You should be using the `chsh` command to change your user's shell.

```
$ chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish
```

#### OSX

On OSX you apparently have to add this to the `/etc/shells` file as described in this issue titled: [OS X refuses to setting fish as default shell(installed via Homebrew) #989](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/989).

To do this you need to run this command to add it to `/etc/shells`:

```
$ echo "/usr/local/bin/fish" | sudo tee -a /etc/shells
```

After that this file will look like this:

```
$ cat /etc/shells
# List of acceptable shells for chpass(1).
# Ftpd will not allow users to connect who are not using
# one of these shells.

/bin/bash
/bin/csh
/bin/ksh
/bin/sh
/bin/tcsh
/bin/zsh
/usr/local/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/fish
```

With the above complete, try the `chsh -s ...` command again and it should work.

#### Why?

This issue seems to arise with how `fish` was installed. If you use `brew install fish` then it's likely that `fish` was properly added to `/etc/shells`. If you install `fish` through some other means, then it's likely that it did not get added as an entry to the `/etc/shells` file.

#### Secondary issue

In some cases the permissions on `/etc` itself may be the issue.

```
$ ll /etc
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel    11B Jan 26  2016 /etc -> private/etc

$ ll -d private/etc/
drwxr-xr-x  96 root  wheel   3.2K Jul 12 18:53 private/etc/
```

These permissions are acceptable, if they're not, you can modify them like this:

```
$ sudo mount -uw / 
$ sudo chmod a+x private/etc
```

With the above changes, `chsh -s ...` should now work.

#### References

- [Change the Shell in Mac OS X Terminal](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/21/change-shell-mac-os-x/)
- [Replacing sh with zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453904/replacing-sh-with-zsh/453913#453913)
- [OS X refuses to setting fish as default shell(installed via Homebrew) #989](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/989)
- [How to fix /etc/ folder on Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/404747/how-to-fix-etc-folder-on-mac-os-x/404756#404756)

Comment: I still don't have fish shell added to my shells file.
When I enter the command-line `$ chsh: /usr/local/bin/fish` 
I get this:
`chsh: /usr/local/bin/fish: non-standard shell` 
I have read from the source I mentioned above that I should add fish shell to /etc/shells before I use this command-line

Comment: @LokmanBoukhoulda - I see your issue now, see updates to the A'er.

Comment: I got this error `$ cat: /etc/shells: No such file or directory`

When I entered the following command-line: 

`$ ls -l /etc/shells`

I got this message: 

`lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  admin  29  9 Jun 00:20 /etc/shells -> ../Cellar/fish/2.7.1/bin/fish`

I'm confused, does the file /etc/shells exist?

Comment: @LokmanBoukhoulda - So it looks like fish just co-opted the `/etc/shells` file and made a link to some other file (link is made using the `ln -s` command. It looks like you had `fish` installed via `brew` based on that `../Cellar/` directory.

Comment: @LokmanBoukhoulda - I'd delete that link and simply re-make that file using the one I showed. `sudo unlink /etc/shells`.

Comment: Find the solution for my problem. My `/etc/`folder was private and that's why it gave me `/etc/shells: No such file or directory` . So by making some research I found the steps to make it public. Here's the `mount -uw /
chmod a+x private/etc`
Source: [link] (https://superuser.com/questions/404747/how-to-fix-etc-folder-on-mac-os-x/404756#404756) . Now `chsh`command worked.

Comment: @LokmanBoukhoulda - interesting...I wonder how that even happened?

Comment: @LokmanBoukhoulda - I added the fix to my A'er.